# Is it possible to modify a value in a Set

Tags: javascript, set

Using a JavaScript [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), is it possible to modify a value previously added?

For example:

```js
const mySet = new Set()
mySet.add(42)

mySet.set(0, 69)
```

`.set` is made up, I just want to modify the set at index 0. Is there any way to do this or should I be using a regular array or even a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

Comment: Try mySet[0] = 69;

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work.

Comment: Well, for starters, why is it const if you want to change it.

And yes, set is just an array for unique values. Its not a dictionary or map that has key value pairs.

Comment: @John `const` just means the reference doesn't change, interior mutability is fine.

Comment: @jhpratt I get that, it just seems redundant. There also is no set function for the set object so I don't know why a const would even be in here.

Comment: const doesn't mean an Array or Set's contents will stay constant as @jhpratt stated. I don't understand your confusion with the const part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to remove it and readd the appropriate value. Sets only contain values, nothing more.

Sets don't have an index. You can use a Map or object, as you suggested.

Comment: Okay thank you :) I went with a regular array for now.